# TextView отображается при visibility = "gone"

Tags: android, textview

Хотите верьте, хотите нет, но `TextView` отображается на макете при `visibility = "gone"`. Прецеденты были? Где искать?

UPDATE

Скриншоты по порядку.

1. TextView в разметке:

[image: TextView tvMid в разметке - visibility="gone"]

2. TextView в результатах поиска (к вопросу о дальнейших манипуляциях с textview):

[image: Никаких манипуляций с textview tvMid, меняющих его visibility, нет]

3. Так выглядит TextView tvMid на макете в Android Studio:

[image: На макете в студии его не видно]

4. И, наконец, так это выглядит на девайсе:

[image: На девайсе tvMid отображается]

UPDATE 2:

Опытным путем выяснилось, что виноват Fundapter от amigo . Видимость меняется здесь:

```
BindDictionary<master> dict = new BindDictionary<master>();
                    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvMid, new StringExtractor<master>() {
                        @Override
                        public String getStringValue(master person, int position) {
                            return person.user_id;
                        }
                    });
```

Подскажите, как лечить?

Comment: Приведите пример вашей разметки, что ли .. и вообще, больше информации, связанной с проблемой. Если все правильно, то таких прецедентов не было, пожалуй, за все время существования Android/

Answer (score 1):

попробуй file > Invalidate caches / Restart

Answer (score 1):

Если среда Android Studio, попробуйте:

`Build > Clean Project`

Затем удалите приложение с девайса и скомпилируйте заново. В подавляющем большинстве случаев помогает с любыми странностями.

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема проявляется в предпросмоторщике разметки студии, то надо просто не пользоваться им, ибо он работает плохо. Если это проявилось на девайсе, то, видимо, у вас включен `instantRun` в настройках студии. Его надо отключить, т.к. он работает также плохо как и предпросмоторщик.

Comment: Попробовал все три варианта - проблема сохранилась

Comment: @Новичок, а если вы создадите пустую активити с пустой разметкой и в неё добавить текстовое поле невидимое - то будет ли оно видно? 99% что нет. Видимо, вы скрываете какие-то детали. Может вы манипулируете где-то видимостью оного?